# Plot intersection of 2 planes in mayavi

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I am trying to render 2 planes and then their intersection line in mayavi.

**Equation of planes**

x - 5*y + 2*z -11 = 0

3*x - 2*y + 3*z -7 = 0

The line where these 2 planes intersect is (I calculated this manually) -

11*x - 3*y - 13*z - 17 = 0

**Code**

```py
%gui qt
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
mlab.clf()

# first plane
x, y = np.mgrid[-100:100:1000j, -100:10:1000j]
z = (-x+5*y+11)/2
mlab.surf(x,y,z, warp_scale='auto',color=(0.1,0.2,0.3))

# second plane
x, y = np.mgrid[-100:100:1000j, -100:100:1000j]
z = (-3*x+2*y+7)/3
mlab.surf(x,y,z, warp_scale='auto')

# intersection line
x = np.linspace(-1000, 1000, num=4000)
y = np.linspace(-1000, 1000, num=4000)
z = (11*x-3*y-17)/13
mlab.points3d(x, y, z,scale_factor=0.95)
```

**Plot**

[image: Imgur]

This is the final plot I am getting, which is clearly wrong. I am not able to find the error here.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple misunderstandings here. You have two planes, with equations x - 5y + 2z -11 = 0 and 3x - 2y + 3z - 7 = 0. Saying that the line where those two planes intersect obeys the equation 11x - 3y - 13z - 17 = 0 is a non-sense. This is the equation of a plane, not a line. And even if the line you are looking for is included in this plane, how do you choose (x, y, z)?

The approach here is to note that all (x, y, z) describing the line describe also the planes, then to express one coordinate according to the others for one plane and finally inject this in the second plane equation. This gives

> y = (-3x - 19) / 11
>
> z = (-x + 5y + 11) / 2

Using the following piece of code

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy
x, y = numpy.mgrid[-10:10:21*1j, -10:10:21*1j]
z = (-x + 5 * y + 11) / 2
zz = (-3 * x + 2 * y + 7) / 3
xx = numpy.linspace(-10, 10, 21)
yy = -3 / 11 * xx - 19 / 11
zzz = (-xx + 5 * yy + 11) / 2
mlab.surf(x, y, z)
mlab.surf(x, y, zz)
mlab.points3d(xx, yy, zzz)
mlab.show()
```

This figure is produced

[image]